# Why must users have a certain amount of reputation to simply view review queues?

Tags: discussion, community, reviewing

I can understand why users would require a certain amount of reputation to, for example, approve and reject edits. I do not, however, understand why users would require a certain amount of reputation to simply view a list of suggested edits. In specific, I primarily enjoy editing posts myself (which I have admittedly done very little of) but have just noticed that I have lost access to the 'Low Quality Posts' queue.

Comment: What's the point of showing you a review queue if you can't review anything in the queue?

Comment: @MBraedley I enjoyed the use of the Low Quality Posts queue via the fact that I could submit edits for low quality posts to improve them.

Comment: From my experience, 90+% of the posts that end up in Low Quality (at least on Arqade) also end up in either First Post or Late Answer (or both).  You'll only really miss out on the occasional quick and dirty answer from an experienced user.

Comment: The review system has been undergoing a makeover, so it's a work in progress. Engaging in the ongoing discussion on Meta.SO is the best way to advertise this as a useful use-case for being able to just view the queue.

Comment: The fact that reviews can be [permalinked](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/35491) seems to make the review system fairly inconsistent.